# Write to Postgres with apache beam (GCP)

Tags: java, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are using apache beam in our google cloud platform and implemented a dataflow streaming job that writes to our postgres database. However, we noticed that once we started using two JdbcIO.write() statements next to each other, our streaming job starts throwing errors like these:

```
Operation ongoing in step JdbcIO.WriteVoid/ParDo(Write) for at least 35m00s without outputting or completing in state process
at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park (Native Method)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:194)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst (LinkedBlockingDeque.java:581)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject (GenericObjectPool.java:439)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject (GenericObjectPool.java:356)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection (PoolingDataSource.java:134)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$WriteVoid$WriteFn.executeBatch (JdbcIO.java:1438)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$WriteVoid$WriteFn.processElement (JdbcIO.java:1387)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$WriteVoid$WriteFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement (Unknown Source)
```

This only occurs approximately 30 minutes after deployment. It is able to process 10.000 elements just fine until those 30-ish minutes later. On average the throughput ranges from 50 elements/second to 120 elements/second.
The queries are not that heavy either, just a simple `delete` and `insert` statement.
We think that the connections are stuck and not released for the other elements but we don't know how to fix it though.

Here's the code:

```
public void writeToPostgres(PCollection<TimestampedValue<KV<String, Duration>>> collection) {
  collection
    .apply(Filter.by(Postgres::filter1))
    .apply(JdbcIO.<TimestampedValue<KV<String, Duration>>>write()
      .withDataSourceProviderFn(JdbcIO.PoolableDataSourceProvider.of(getDataSourceConfiguration()))
      .withStatement("DELETE FROM table1 where field1 = ?::UUID and field2=?")
      .withPreparedStatementSetter((element, statement) -> {
        statement.setString(1, element.getValue().getKey());
        Instant timestamp = element.getTimestamp();
        statement.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(timestamp.getMillis()));
      })
    .withBatchSize(1)
    .withRetryStrategy(DEADLOCK_DETECTED_RETRY_STRATEGY));

  collection
    .apply(Filter.by(Postgres::filter2))
    .apply(
      JdbcIO.<TimestampedValue<KV<String, Duration>>>write()
        .withDataSourceProviderFn(JdbcIO.PoolableDataSourceProvider.of(getDataSourceConfiguration()))
    .withStatement("INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2) \n" +
      "VALUES (?::UUID, ?) \n" +
      "ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT someconstraint\n" +
      "DO UPDATE SET field2 = excluded.field2")
    .withPreparedStatementSetter((element, statement) -> {
      Instant eventTime = element.getTimestamp();
      Timestamp now = Timestamp.from(now());

      statement.setString(1, element.getValue().getKey());
      statement.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(eventTime.getMillis()));
    })
    .withBatchSize(1)
    .withRetryStrategy(DEADLOCK_DETECTED_RETRY_STRATEGY)
  );
}

...

private DataSourceConfiguration getDataSourceConfiguration() {
    return DataSourceConfiguration.create(ValueProvider.StaticValueProvider.of("org.postgresql.Driver"), jdbcUrlProvider)
                .withUsername(usernameProvider)
                .withPassword(passwordProvider);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know enough about JdbcIO to put this as a full answer, but reading through [the code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/2a2107af70dea8c34743cb009be7904b6497858b/sdks/java/io/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.java#L1693) it looks like you're right, the connections are opened and not closed until the ParDo is finalized, which happens when the pipeline is finishing. Do both these transforms connect to the same DataSource?

Comment: @DanielOliveira Yes that is correct. The `update` and `insert` statements are performed on the same database and table with the same username and password. I will edit the question to show how the `getDataSourceConfiguration` function looks like.

Answer (score 1):

We were able to find a fix but I consider this to be more of a workaround because we didn't find anything within the DataSourceProvider of JdbcIO. We basically copied the `PoolableDataSourceProvider` of `JdbcIO` and used the HikariDataSource instead because it seems to improve performance anyway.

First, we add the hikariCP dependency in out pom file

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
     <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's how the HikariDataSourceProvider looks like:

```
public static class HikariDataSourceProvider implements SerializableFunction<Void, DataSource> {
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<HikariDataSourceConfig, DataSource> instances = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private final HikariDataSourceConfig config;

    private HikariDataSourceProvider(HikariDataSourceConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public static SerializableFunction<Void, DataSource> of(HikariDataSourceConfig hikariDataSourceConfig) {
        return new HikariDataSourceProvider(hikariDataSourceConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource apply(Void input) {
        return instances.computeIfAbsent(
                config,
                ignored -> {
                    HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
                        hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(config.getJdbcUrlProvider().get());
                        hikariDataSource.setUsername(config.getUsernameProvider().get());
                        hikariDataSource.setPassword(config.getPasswordProvider().get());
                        hikariDataSource.setAutoCommit(false);
                        return hikariDataSource;
                });
    }
}
...

@Data
@Builder
public static class HikariDataSourceConfig implements Serializable {
    private final ValueProvider<String> jdbcUrlProvider;
    private final ValueProvider<String> usernameProvider;
    private final ValueProvider<String> passwordProvider;
}
```

The `@Data` and `@Builder` are lombok annotations.

The PTransform would look something like this:

```
JdbcIO.<TimestampedValue<KV<String, Duration>>>write()
     .withDataSourceProviderFn(HikariDataSourceProvider.of(getDataSourceConfig()))
     .withStatement("...
```

We also removed the `.withBatchSize(1)` line so it doesn't bottleneck the process. We tried just removing this line first without the HikariDataSource but that alone did not solve this issue.

The streaming job can now handle the statements and is stable. The error no longer occurs.